# Indefinite article

Tags: articles

We say: a child goes to school or is at school (as a pupil). I wonder if an article is necessary in this sentence:

“I have already chosen a school for my daughter.” “Really? Are you sending her
 to ***a*** public or private school?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

We speak about going to school, college or university in general, meaning going to an educational institution.

We say: **I'm going to fetch my children from school**, meaning from their place of education rather than the specific school they are attending.

But when talking about a specific school, such as one you have chosen for your daughter, you have selected **a** school.

You could say you have selected **the** school to which you intend to send your daughter - or **a** school to which you intend to send your daughter..

In this context both articles would be correct.

Once she begins attending there, she is **going to school** (meaning to be educated) at **the** school (meaning the particular institution that) you have selected.

This is likely to be **a** good school.

Comment: But I don't think *public* or *private* is necessarily specific enough. People say things like *I went to public school* or *I sent my kid to private school*. We can turn those sentences into interrogatives and say *Did you send your kid to private school?*. However, I'd say in the sentence given by the asker, the speaker is more likely to say ***a** public school* because the previous sentence contains ***a** school*.